# Is Android SDK version relevant when compiling libraries using NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, qt-creator, android-sdk-tools

**First step:** I use QtCreator to compile a bunch of libraries (.so files) + a GUI test program to test those libraries on an Android device.

**Second step:** After I tested them, I re-compile the libraries without the GUI test program and send them to a client who's going to integrate those .so file in its own Andoid application (generating and apk), not using QtCreator anymore. I do this step using QtCreator (because it's setup, very easy for me to just remove the GUI test program and hit compile), but I'm pretty sure they could also be compiled directly using ndk-build if I work on writting the correct make files for that.

When I re-compile the libraries, there's still a "Android build SDK" option under "Build Android APK" set to "android-22" in QtCreator. However, my client generates its final app for "android-19". And we are wondering if this could be a problem.

My understanding is that my .so files generated in "second step" are built using the NDK only (SDK is not used, so android API version "android-22" is irrelevant as I do not generate any APK...). So there should be no compatibility issue when those .so files are integrated in an application, as far as the same NDK version is used.

Am I right?

Comment: _However, my client generates its final app for "android-19"_ - is it `minimal` or `target` SDK version?

Comment: QtCreator GUI does not detail that, it's "Android build SDK" option under "Build Android APK"....no more info.

Comment: For the NDK, target and minimal are equivalent.